# Is it possible to scaffold a new environment using the Angular CLI?

Tags: angular, angular-cli

Is there a way to leverage the Angular CLI and provide it a command to create/scaffold a new environmental configuration? Out of the box with `ng new` we get the ability to build locally via `ng build` and have a production build via `ng build --prod.` I want to add an environment like 'QA' or 'Test' for example and I *can* do this easily by hand rolling the required configurations inside of the `environments` folder and updating the sections in `angular.json`. However, is there a way to leverage the CLI and it's commands to scaffold a new configuration environment and have it update `angular.json`, or am I required to always hand roll and do this manually?

I looked at the documentation and haven't seen anything exactly, but wondered if I'm missing anything or if it's possible? https://angular.io/cli/generate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: No.
All options that the CLI could generate are [listed here](https://angular.io/cli/generate)

Since you are allowed to add to the environemnt whatever you like, it makes sense that the CLI doesn't try to generate this file for you.

However it is possible to wirte a schematic that does exaclty this for you (but explaining how to create schematics is beond the scope of this question). 
The benefit of this approach is that you can customize the schematic exactly to your needs and therefore the generated environment will look exactly as intended.

- [Schematics Indtroduction](https://blog.angular.io/schematics-an-introduction-dc1dfbc2a2b2)